# Set command option with document wide newcommand

Tags: macros, siunitx, key-value

I work a lot with the `siunitx` package and I've got many numbers with a high decimal precision. Now I'd like to be able to just copy these numbers in full precision in the relevant positions in text, equations and tables and adjust the precision in the preamble of the document.

Is there any way to pass options to commands by predefining the option string? I can easily make it work when the string it is not used as a command option, but for command options it is not working...

My minimal example:

```latex
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,twosided]{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\newcommand{\rndprc}{round-mode=places,round-precision=4}%    command option string
\newcommand{\Tk}{\Theta}%    this works...

\begin{document}        
    \paragraph{testing commands...}
    \num[\rndprc]{12.34567890123}

    This is working: $\Tk$ 

\end{document}
```

Any idea how I can make this work? Best case would be to have something like `\newcommand{\rndprc}[1]{round-mode=places,round-precision={#1}}`, so I can enter the precision in place.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Macros aren't expanded by the key-val parser. You can, instead of a macro, define a `.meta` key which sets the options you want in one go. You can also give an argument and a default value to the key:

```latex
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,twosided]{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\keys_define:nn { siunitx }
  {
    rndprc .meta:n =
      {
        round-mode = places,
        round-precision = #1,
      },
    rndprc .default:n = 4,
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\newcommand{\Tk}{\Theta}

\begin{document}
\paragraph{testing commands...}
\num[rndprc]{12.34567890123}

\num[rndprc=3]{12.34567890123}

This is working: $\Tk$
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is this also working with an additional argument to locally set the precision?

Comment: @Scotty1- Yes, it is :) I expanded the answer.

Comment: Awesome and thanks alot!

Answer (score 1):

Locally change the `sisetup`:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,twosided]{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\newcommand{\rndprc}[1][4]{%
    \sisetup{round-mode=places,round-precision=#1}%  # command option string
}
\newcommand{\Tk}{\Theta}%  # this works...

\begin{document}        
    \paragraph{testing commands...}
    {\rndprc\num{12.34567890123}}

    {\rndprc[3]\num{12.34567890123}}

    This is working: $\Tk$ 

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there also any possibility to pass the command to the options of `\num`, as in `\num[\rndprc[3]]{12.34567890123}`? Prepending the sisetup each time within brackets seems like a workaround.

Comment: @Scotty1- No, this has to be done outside.